# Control Resizing Issue in Winforms (DPI Scaling)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, scaling

I have a winforms App.It uses a custom knob control.The app was originally designed on a 20 inch 720P monitor.Now when it comes to 1080P 15 inch laptop there is a scaling issue.To overcome this i have set the `AutoscaleMode` Property of some forms to `DPI`.This works quite well for most forms.But when it comes to the form below that uses a custom Knob control,there is a white spacing left around the area.

This is the complete code for the know Control

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KnobControl
{

    // A delegate type for hooking up ValueChanged notifications. 
    public delegate void ValueChangedEventHandler(object Sender);

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for KnobControl.
    /// </summary>
    public class KnobControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        private int _Minimum = 0;
        private int _Maximum = 25;
        private int _LargeChange = 5;
        private int _SmallChange = 1;
        private bool _ShowSmallScale = false;
        private bool _ShowLargeScale = true;
        private bool _isFocused = false;


        private int _Value = 0;
        private bool isKnobRotating = false;
        private Rectangle rKnob ;
        private Point pKnob;
        private Rectangle rScale;
        private Pen DottedPen;

        Brush bKnob;
        Brush bKnobPoint;
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // declare Off screen image and Offscreen graphics       
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        private Image OffScreenImage;
        private Graphics gOffScreen;
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever 
        // the Value is Changed.                                 
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        public event ValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged;
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Invoke the ValueChanged event; called  when value     
        // is changed                                            
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        protected virtual void OnValueChanged(object sender) 
        {
            if (ValueChanged != null)
                ValueChanged(sender);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows Small Scale marking.
        /// </summary>
        public bool ShowSmallScale
        {
            get{return _ShowSmallScale;}
            set
            {
                _ShowSmallScale = value;
                // need to redraw 
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows Large Scale marking
        /// </summary>
        public bool ShowLargeScale
        {
            get{return _ShowLargeScale;}
            set
            {
                _ShowLargeScale = value;
                // need to redraw
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Minimum Value for knob Control
        /// </summary>
        public int Minimum 
        {
            get{return _Minimum;}
            set{_Minimum = value;}
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Maximum value for knob control
        /// </summary>
        public int Maximum 
        {
            get{return _Maximum;}
            set{_Maximum = value;}
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// value set for large change
        /// </summary>
        public int LargeChange 
        {
            get{return _LargeChange;}
            set
            {
                _LargeChange = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// value set for small change.
        /// </summary>
        public int SmallChange 
        {
            get{return _SmallChange;}
            set
            {
                _SmallChange = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Current Value of knob control
        /// </summary>
        public int Value
        {
            get{return _Value;}
            set
            {

                _Value = value;
                // need to redraw 
                Refresh();
                // call delegate  
                OnValueChanged(this); 
            }
        }

        public KnobControl()
        {

            // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
            DottedPen = new Pen(Utility.getDarkColor(this.BackColor,40));
            DottedPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
            DottedPen.DashCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashCap.Flat;

            InitializeComponent();
            setDimensions();


            // TODO: Add any initialization after the InitForm call

        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            // Set background color of Image...            
            gOffScreen.Clear(this.BackColor);
            // Fill knob Background to give knob effect....
            gOffScreen.FillEllipse(bKnob,rKnob);
            // Set antialias effect on                     
            gOffScreen.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias ;
            // Draw border of knob                         
            gOffScreen.DrawEllipse(new Pen(this.BackColor),rKnob);

            //if control is focused 
            if (this._isFocused)
            {
                gOffScreen.DrawEllipse(DottedPen,rKnob);
            }

            // get current position of pointer             
            Point Arrow = this.getKnobPosition();

            // Draw pointer arrow that shows knob position 
            Utility.DrawInsetCircle(ref gOffScreen,new Rectangle(Arrow.X-3 ,Arrow.Y-3,6,6),new Pen(this.BackColor));

            //---------------------------------------------
            // darw small and large scale                  
            //---------------------------------------------
            if(this._ShowSmallScale)
            {
                    for (int i= Minimum ; i<=Maximum ;i+= this._SmallChange)
                    {
                        gOffScreen.DrawLine(new Pen(this.ForeColor),getMarkerPoint(0,i),getMarkerPoint(3,i));
                    }
            }
            if(this._ShowLargeScale)
            {
                for (int i= Minimum ; i<=Maximum ;i+= this._LargeChange)
                {
                    gOffScreen.DrawLine(new Pen(this.ForeColor),getMarkerPoint(0,i),getMarkerPoint(5,i));
                }
            }

            // Drawimage on screen                    
            g.DrawImage(OffScreenImage,0,0);
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Empty To avoid Flickring due do background Drawing.
        }
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Utility.isPointinRectangle(new Point(e.X,e.Y),rKnob))
            {
                // Start Rotation of knob         
                this.isKnobRotating = true;
            }

        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------
        // we need to override IsInputKey method to allow user to   
        // use up, down, right and bottom keys other wise using this
        // keys will change focus from current object to another    
        // object on the form                                       
        //----------------------------------------------------------
        protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys key) 
        { 
            switch(key) 
            { 
                case Keys.Up: 
                case Keys.Down: 
                case Keys.Right: 
                case Keys.Left: 
                return true; 
            } 
            return base.IsInputKey(key); 
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Stop rotation                   
            this.isKnobRotating = false;
            if (Utility.isPointinRectangle(new Point(e.X,e.Y),rKnob))
            {
                // get value                   
                this.Value = this.getValueFromPosition(new Point(e.X,e.Y));
            }
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //--------------------------------------
            //  Following Handles Knob Rotating     
            //--------------------------------------
            if (this.isKnobRotating == true)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                int posVal = this.getValueFromPosition(p);
                Value = posVal;
            }

        }

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            this._isFocused = true;
            this.Refresh();
            base.OnEnter(new EventArgs());
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            this._isFocused = false;
            this.Refresh();
            base.OnLeave(new EventArgs());
        }


        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if(components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // KnobControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(120F, 120F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.On;
            this.Name = "KnobControl";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.KnobControl_Load);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.KnobControl_Resize);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        private void setDimensions()
        {
            // get smaller from height and width
            int size = this.Width ;
            if (this.Width > this.Height)
            {
                size = this.Height;
            }
            // allow 10% gap on all side to determine size of knob    
            this.rKnob = new Rectangle((int)(size*0.10),(int)(size*0.10),(int)(size*0.80),(int)(size*0.80));

            this.rScale = new Rectangle(2,2,size-4,size-4);

            this.pKnob = new Point(rKnob.X + rKnob.Width/2, rKnob.Y + rKnob.Height/2);
            // create offscreen image                                 
            this.OffScreenImage = new Bitmap(this.Width,this.Height);
            // create offscreen graphics                              
            this.gOffScreen = Graphics.FromImage(OffScreenImage);   

            // create LinearGradientBrush for creating knob            
            bKnob = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
                rKnob,Utility.getLightColor(this.BackColor,55),Utility.getDarkColor(this.BackColor,55),LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
            // create LinearGradientBrush for knobPoint                
            bKnobPoint = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
                rKnob,Utility.getLightColor(this.BackColor,55),Utility.getDarkColor(this.BackColor,55),LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
        }

        private void KnobControl_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            setDimensions();
            Refresh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// gets knob position that is to be drawn on control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Point that describes current knob position</returns>
        private Point getKnobPosition()
        {
            double degree = 270* this.Value/(this.Maximum-this.Minimum);
            degree = (degree +135)*Math.PI /180;

            Point Pos = new Point(0,0);
            Pos.X = (int)(Math.Cos(degree)*(rKnob.Width/2-10)  + rKnob.X + rKnob.Width/2);
            Pos.Y = (int)(Math.Sin(degree)*(rKnob.Width/2-10)  + rKnob.Y + rKnob.Height/2);
            return Pos;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// gets marker point required to draw scale marker.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="length">distance from center</param>
        /// <param name="Value">value that is to be marked</param>
        /// <returns>Point that describes marker position</returns>
        private Point getMarkerPoint(int length,int Value)
        {
            double degree = 270* Value/(this.Maximum-this.Minimum);
            degree = (degree +135)*Math.PI /180;

            Point Pos = new Point(0,0);
            Pos.X = (int)(Math.Cos(degree)*(rKnob.Width/2-length + 7)  + rKnob.X + rKnob.Width/2);
            Pos.Y = (int)(Math.Sin(degree)*(rKnob.Width/2-length + 7) + rKnob.Y + rKnob.Height/2);
            return Pos;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// converts geomatrical position in to value..
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p">Point that is to be converted</param>
        /// <returns>Value derived from position</returns>
        private int getValueFromPosition(Point p)
        {
            double degree = 0.0;
            int v = 0;
            if (p.X <= pKnob.X )
            {
                degree  = (double)(pKnob.Y - p.Y ) /  (double)(pKnob.X - p.X );
                degree = Math.Atan(degree);
                degree = (degree) *(180/Math.PI) + 45;
                v = (int)(degree * (this.Maximum-this.Minimum)/ 270);

            }
            else if (p.X > pKnob.X )
            {
                degree  = (double)(p.Y - pKnob.Y ) /  (double)(p.X - pKnob.X );
                degree = Math.Atan(degree);
                degree = 225 + (degree) *(180/Math.PI);
                v = (int)(degree * (this.Maximum-this.Minimum)/ 270);

            }
            if (v > Maximum) v=Maximum;
            if (v < Minimum) v=Minimum;
            return v;

        }

        private void KnobControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



    }
}
```

How can i sort this issue,Please advice.

[image]

Comment: The DrawImage() call is wrong, it does not scale the bitmap to fit the control.  You need to use the overload that takes a Rectangle argument.  This will affect the quality of the image, it will get fuzzy.  Although it ought to be barely visible on this one.  Supporting multiple DPI settings and getting perfect images *does* require having multiple image resources.  Like the way it is done in a UWP app.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your answer..What should be the coordinates and sizing of the rectangle...?

Comment: Use this.DisplayRectangle

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot,it worked perfect :)

Comment: @HansPassant I have another issue,when a user decides to increase the size using the `Change the size of the text,app and other items option` in Windows 10 display settings, the Main Winform window gets cut.How can i solve this .. Please advice...Any help is very much appreciated